# select the max element in an increasing (and restarting over) list

Tags: python, list

I have this list:

```
mylist = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 
          1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3]
```

The length of the list is : `38`.

I want a new list with length: `32`.

My new list will be:

```
new_list = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 
            1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3]
```

So, the numbers represent different counts. The first `19` elements of the `mylist` are all `1`.  The `20` and `21` elements are `1` and `2`. This means I had 2 counts.

I want to get rid of the `1` and keep only the `2` because I have 2 counts. The same goes to the next `1 and 2` elements and to the last  `1, 2, 3` elements. There, I have a max count of `3`.

If I try something like this:

```
new_list = []
for idx in range(len(mylist)-1):
    if mylist[idx] == 1:
        if mylist[idx + 1] > mylist[idx]:
            new_list.append(mylist[idx + 1])
        else:
            new_list.append(mylist[idx])
```

because I am only checking the current and next elements, I miss the last `3`.

Comment: The logic is unclear, how does it generalize? Do you just want to remove 1s when they are followed by a greater value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing the first element in mylist is less than 2 then:

```
mylist = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 
          1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3]
newlist = []

for x in mylist:
    if x > 1:
        newlist[-1] = x
    else:
        newlist.append(x)

print(newlist)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me rephrase the question.
Starting from the following list of integers

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 
 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3]
```

we want to obtain the following list

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, __ 2, 1, 1, 
 1, 1, __ 2, 1, 1, 1, __ 2, 1, __ 2, __ __ 3]
```

by removing the elements that are marked with `__`.
This means, we only keep the highest number of any sequence of increasing numbers, so `1,2` becomes `2` and `1,2,3` becomes `3`, but any `1` that is not followed by `2` stays `1`.

My suggestion is to iterate through the full list; at every `1` (which could be the start of a new increasing sequence), we iterate through the remaining list and keep the highest element we find before the next `1`. Here's how I would implement this:

```
new_list = []
for idx, item in enumerate(mylist):
    if item == 1:
        for next_item in mylist[idx+1:]:
            if next_item == 1:
                break
            item = next_item
        new_list.append(item)
```

We don't need to check whether an item is larger than the next item, because we know that the next item can only be `1` or one larger than the current item.

---

**Edit:** My original answer (below) misunderstood the question.

If I understand your question correctly, you want to modify your loop so that it also compares the last element of your list to the first element. In this case, I would use the modulo operator `%` to jump from the last element with index `len(mylist) - 1` to the first element with index `0`.
Here's how I would modify your code example:

```
new_list = []
n_items = len(mylist)
for idx in range(n_items):
    if mylist[idx] == 1:
        if mylist[(idx + 1) % n_items] > mylist[idx]:
            new_list.append(mylist[(idx + 1) % n_items])
        else:
            new_list.append(mylist[idx])
```

Furthermore, I would suggest simplifying it to:

```
new_list = []
n_items = len(mylist)
for idx, item in enumerate(mylist):
    if item == 1:
        if mylist[(idx + 1) % n_items] > 1:
            new_list.append(mylist[(idx + 1) % n_items])
        else:
            new_list.append(1)
```

Comment: The last element of the new list should be `3` and not `2` since we have `1,2,3`.

Comment: Oh, I believe I misunderstood the question, sorry! Is the task to replace every `1,2,3` in the list with `3`, every `1,2` with `2`, and keep every `1` that is not followed by `2`? Can there be numbers larger than 3 in the list?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Yes, there may be more than 3.

Comment: Okay, I think I understood your question now and edited my answer accordingly.